# Running commands inside a script as root/ not asking for password

Tags: ubuntu

I am fairly new to ubuntu and am having some issues with scripting.
I have a script that runs well, however it asks for the users password then runs the commands with sudo.
I have now run into the issue where an account is not in the sudoers file, this breaks my script.
I would like to have this script run without asking for a password and whether or not the user is in the sudoers file.
So far I have not been able to find anything that works

Answer (score 0):

when you use [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to run a command, that command is run as a super user (sudo means Super User Do), which gives it access to some parts of the system which are necessarily protected. You cannot directly allow users who aren't sudoers to run a script which requires sudo. Instead, you should look at what operation they need to perform which requires sudo. If, for example, they need to access some data which you intend to be shared, but which isn't accessible without sudo, [you can change the permissions on that data](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/). Other solutions may be available depending on your needs.